# Backbone.js only dispatching 'add' one time

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In an attempt to understand Backbone.js more, I made a dummy blog with Backbone.js.
I have a 'create post' button. When I click that button it I run:

```
posts.create({title: makeid(),content: makeid()})
```

(`makeId()` just generates some random characters.)
Create should dispatch an `add` event that I listen for. That `add` event dispatches only 1 time. I don't know why.  I have left a bunch of console.log in the code to show what I tried.  On the server side I return all the models on create. I can't seem to find documentation on what the server should return. 
Here is the `app.js`

```
$(function(){

    var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            id: '',
            title : 'Untitled',
            content: 'No content'
        }, 
        urlRoot : '/posts/'
    });

    var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : Post,
        url: '/posts/'
    });

    var posts = new Posts;

    var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tag: 'li',

        template: _.template($("#post-template").html()),

        events: {
            "click .delete-post" : 'deletePost'
        },

        initalize: function(){
            //this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
        },

        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },
        deletePost: function(){
            console.log(this.model);
            this.model.destroy();
            this.$el.remove()
        }
    });

    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $("#home"),

        events:{
            "click #add-post": "addPost"
        },

        initialize: function(){
            this.listenTo(posts, 'add', this.addOne);
            posts.on("add", function(post){
                console.log('post added: ' + post);
            });
            posts.fetch({ update: true });
        },

        addPost:function(){
            console.log('add post')
            posts.create({
                title: makeid(), 
                content: makeid()
            },{success: function(){console.log('success');}
            });
        },

        addOne: function(post){
            console.log('one was added');
            var view = new PostView({model:post});
            this.$("#posts").append(view.render().el);
        },

        render: function(){
            if(posts.length){
                console.log('rendering');
            }
        }
    });
    var appView = new AppView;
});

function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
```

Here is my `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Backbone test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6" id="home">
            <a href="#" id="add-post" class="btn btn-mini btn-success">add post</a>
            <ul id="posts">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>




<script id="post-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="span4">
    <h3>
        <%- title %>
        <br />
        <a href='#' class='btn btn-mini btn-primary'>edit</a>
        <a href='#' class='btn btn-mini btn-danger delete-post'>delete</a>
    </h3>
    <p><%- content %></p>
</div>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you assign an id server side to your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Backbone won't add models with the same `id` in a collection.
- Your models have a default `id` set to an empty string, but any value non `undefined` or `null` would yield the same result.
- The models returned by your server don't have an `id` set, the default one is used.

What happens is that the first created model takes the default `id` and is added to the collection. When you create the second one, it is also instantiated with the default `id`, but it can't be added to the collection. See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/vfEVC/ for a demo.

Either remove the default `id` or assign one server side to get both instances in your collection.

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/vfEVC/1/